# How do I find out the size of the Rails download and its installation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

I would like to find out the size of the file downloaded, and the size of all files created upon the installation initiated by:

```
gem install rails
```

How can I find out the file size of both the download and the Rails installation?

Comment: There are *many* things that are downloaded since the Rails gem has many dependancies, do you count those? The same question applies to the "installation".

Comment: Yes, as I wanted to say, I want to know the sizes of both all downloads and the final installation upon the execution of the command: gem install rails.

Comment: Yes, what is going to be downloaded when you type in the command above? How many MB/GB??

Answer (score 7):

One way you can do this is the `disk usage` command.

By running the `disk usage` command upon the Rails directory, one can see the size of the directory:

```
du -sh </rails/directory>
```

The location of the directory is necessarily dependent on what setup you have (I have different Rails versions installed in a few Debian virtual machines, but 3.1 on my MacPorts-hacked OS X).

Comment: wow, thanks, Bill the Lizard!  I hope the scales are in good shape!  Most people on this earth do not appreciate herpetology as much as one would hope.

Comment: Where is this dubious rails directory? I don't have /rails/directory. Is there no standard location?

Answer (score 2):

You can find out the total size of a rails project using Bundler.

First create the app and `cd` into it:

```
$ rails new test_app --skip-bundle
$ cd test_app
```

Then bundle it using the `--path` option:

```
$ bundle --path vendor
```

Then calculate the disk usage for the directory:

```
$ du -sh .
```

On my system (OSX Lion) the result was **41MB**

Answer (score 0):

You can always see what was installed for a particular gem using something like `gem contents rails` but that only shows the gem in isolation, not its dependencies. Dependencies are listed on the [gem page](http://rubygems.org/gems/rails) and are available though the [Rubygems API](http://guides.rubygems.org/rubygems-org-api/).

You can use `File::Stat` to get information on those files which includes size. When downloaded, though, I believe these are compressed into a `.gem` file which tends to be smaller than the installed size.